# How to perform aggregation operation using Spring Data JPA for a date?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data

**Scenario:**

In a web application I am getting order from client for a particular date. I have to perform aggregation operation on these orders date wise. For e.g., I want sum(quantity1),sum(quantity2),sum(quantity3),.... for 18th Oct, 2021 where Orders status need to be **"PLACED"**(neither cancelled nor Delivered) .

**Exception:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'journeyFoodServiceImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'journeyFoodServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\TiaaUser\Desktop\AWS\journeyfood\target\classes\org\brahmakumaris\journeyfood\service\JourneyFoodServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'journeyFoodOrderRepository' defined in org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.repository.JourneyFoodOrderRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.repository.JourneyFoodOrderRepository.getOrdersByDateAndNotDisabled(java.lang.String,java.util.Date)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'journeyFoodServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\TiaaUser\Desktop\AWS\journeyfood\target\classes\org\brahmakumaris\journeyfood\service\JourneyFoodServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'journeyFoodOrderRepository' defined in org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.repository.JourneyFoodOrderRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.repository.JourneyFoodOrderRepository.getOrdersByDateAndNotDisabled(java.lang.String,java.util.Date)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'journeyFoodOrderRepository' defined in org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.repository.JourneyFoodOrderRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.repository.JourneyFoodOrderRepository.getOrdersByDateAndNotDisabled(java.lang.String,java.util.Date)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List org.brahmakumaris.journeyfood.repository.JourneyFoodOrderRepository.getOrdersByDateAndNotDisabled(java.lang.String,java.util.Date)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56)
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.type.Type.sqlTypes(org.hibernate.engine.spi.Mapping)" because "type" is null
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions$SumFunction.determineJdbcTypeCode(StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions$SumFunction.getReturnType(StandardAnsiSqlAggregationFunctions.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findFunctionReturnType(SessionFactoryHelper.java:430)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.AggregateNode.getDataType(AggregateNode.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructorArgumentTypes(ConstructorNode.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.prepare(ConstructorNode.java:133)
    ... 79 common frames omitted
```

I am facing above mentioned exceptions while perform operation. I have tried by creating below mentioned method in **JourneyFoodOrderRepository** interface-

```
@Repository
public interface JourneyFoodOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<JourneyFoodOrder, Long>{

    @Modifying
    @Query("SELECT new AggregateJourneyFoodOrder(SUM(head_count), SUM(bread), SUM(achar), SUM(jam) ,SUM(others), SUM(puri), SUM(roti), SUM(thepla), mealRetrievalDate)"
            + "  FROM JourneyFoodOrder j WHERE j.orderStatus=:orderStatus AND j.mealRetrievalDate = :mealRetrievalDate")
    List<AggregateJourneyFoodOrder> getOrdersByDateAndNotDisabled(@Param("orderStatus")String orderStatus, @Param("mealRetrievalDate")Date mealRetrievalDate);
}
```

**JourneyFoodOrder.java**

```
@Entity
public class JourneyFoodOrder{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long orderId;
    
    private Integer headCount;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date dateOfOrderPlaced;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private LocalDate dateOfDeparture;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private LocalDate mealRetrievalDate;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "hh:mm:ss a")
    private LocalTime mealRetrievalTime;

    @ManyToOne
    private UserEntity user; 
    
    private Integer thepla;
    
    private Integer puri;
    
    private Integer roti;

    private Integer achar;
    
    private Integer jam;
    
    private Integer bread;
    
    private Integer others;
    
    private String orderStatus;

    //Getter setter and constructor
 }
```

**AggregateJourneyFoodOrder.java**

```
@Entity
public class AggregateJourneyFoodOrder {
    private long totalHeadCount;
    private long totalBread;
    private long totalAchar;
    private long totalJam;
    private long totalOthers;
    private long totalPuri;
    private long totalRoti;
    private long totalThepla;
    @Id
    private LocalDate mealRetrievalDate;
    //Getters/setters/constructors
}
```

Service code
**JourneyFoodServiceImpl.java**

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class JourneyFoodServiceImpl implements JourneyFoodService {
    private final JourneyFoodOrderRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private UserService defaultUserService;
    
    public JourneyFoodServiceImpl(JourneyFoodOrderRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }   
    @Override
    public List<AggregateJourneyFoodOrder> getOrdersByDateAndNotDisabled(LocalDate mealRetrievalDate) {

    return repository.getOrdersByDateAndNotDisabled("PLACED",mealRetrievalDate);
        //return null;
    }

}
```

Controller code
**AdminController.java**

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {
    @Autowired
    private JourneyFoodService journeyFoodServiceImpl;
    
    @GetMapping("/fetchTotalQuantityForADate")
public String fetchTotalQuantityForADate(SubmitFetchTotalQuantityModelByDate submitFetchTotalQuantityModelByDate) {
    return "FetchTotalQuantityForADate";
}

@PostMapping("/fetchTotalQuantityForADate")
public String fetchSumOfJourneyFoodOrdersNotDisabled( @Valid @ModelAttribute("submitFetchTotalQuantityModelByDate") SubmitFetchTotalQuantityModelByDate submitFetchTotalQuantityModelByDate
        , BindingResult result, Model model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        LOGGER.error("AdminController updateOrder method - Error occured");
        return "FetchTotalQuantityForADate";
    }
    LOGGER.info("AdminController fetchSumOfJourneyFoodOrdersNotDisabled method - Enter");
    AggregateJourneyFoodOrder order=journeyFoodServiceImpl.getOrdersByDateAndNotDisabled(submitFetchTotalQuantityModelByDate.getMealRetrievalDate());
     model.addAttribute("order", order==null?null:order);
    LOGGER.info("AdminController fetchSumOfJourneyFoodOrdersNotDisabled method - Exit =>orders: "+order);
    return "fetchAggregateQuantityOrdersByDate";
}
}
```

I have tried solution mentioned in [source](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries-custom-result-with-aggregation-functions)
.Please let me know what exactly I am doing wrong here causing mentioned exceptions.
Thanks

Comment: You have to debug your code. not sure you paste the section that has the problem. you can paste all flow to provide the real picture.

Comment: I cannot debug my code as it's failing on startup only. As mentioned Bean creation is failing for **JourneyFoodOrderRepository.class** . And I am sure issue is with mentioned query. BTW I am adding Controller and Service flow as you have asked, if it helps in any way.

Comment: Does `JourneyFoodService` have @service annotation?

Comment: It's mentioned here `@Transactional
@Service
public class JourneyFoodServiceImpl implements JourneyFoodService {.......}`

Comment: Try to comment out the abstract method and check if application starts. next step, print SQL parameters and try to run this query on DB. these steps will make sure something is wrong in the abstract method

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was issue with my query itself -

1. I have changed my query to below query
2. Removed @Modifying annotation : This annotation will cause issue because updating will return either int or void, and as we are not updating anything so it's not required here)

   @Query("SELECT new AggregateJourneyFoodOrder(SUM(headCount), SUM(bread), SUM(achar), SUM(jam) ,SUM(others), SUM(puri), SUM(roti), SUM(thepla), mealRetrievalDate) FROM JourneyFoodOrder j WHERE j.orderStatus=:orderStatus AND j.mealRetrievalDate = :mealRetrievalDate")
   AggregateJourneyFoodOrder getOrdersByDateAndNotDisabled(@Param("orderStatus")String orderStatus, @Param("mealRetrievalDate")LocalDate mealRetrievalDate);